# Unable to create a Master-detail link on Campaign Member

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary, campaign-member

I have a scenario where I have to roll up the count of active campaigns that a contact is enrolled in.

To achieve this, I tried to create a master-detail on the Campaign Member to the contact. But I am not able to find this data type option when creating a new field.

I first assumed its because of existing data. But then I deleted all the data in Dev Sandbox and I still don't see the option.

What am I missing in this scenario? Is it not possible to create a Master-Detail for Standard objects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really create a M-D relationship between standard objects. Even though it is not explicitly mentioned, but if you see this note from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm), standard objects cannot be on detail side (of custom and that of any standard object either) and that kind of says it.

> You can define master-detail relationships between custom objects or between a custom object and a standard object. However, the standard object cannot be on the detail side of a relationship with a custom object. In addition, you cannot create a master-detail relationship in which the User or Lead objects are the master.

The option of creating a M-D is not available on any of the standard objects in Salesforce when you create a field and only on custom objects because of this fact. I also came across [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HBN2) to allow M-D between standard objects.

What you need here is a bit of customization either using process builder or apex triggers to be able to roll up the counts of contacts on the campaign member.

Comment: Inasmuch as it's rolling up across a junction object based on criteria on the other parent, it sounds to me like a Scheduled Rollup with DLRS might be the best solution (otherwise you end up maintaining two triggers, I think?)

Comment: @DavidReed Yeah, I would think so. Need to research a bit on the most viable solution option. But definitely it ends up not straight out of the box as with rollup summaries.

Comment: In my opinion, the Contact - CampaignMember link should have been a master-detail by default rather than a lookup. The batch looks like the only viable solution, but at the cost of being not real-time. Thank you JayantDas and @DavidReed for your inputs.